# insertion through variable in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data into mysql table through user defined variables. Here is what i am doing. Its gives no error but also don't upload any data into table.

```
$sql="insert into table(".$columns_name.") values(".$val.")";
```

Here is how the the values of the variables are:
$columns_name= col1, col2, col3, col4
$val= aa, 11, 22, bb

Comment: try $sql="insert into table('".$columns_name."') values('".$val."')";

Comment: Your `$val` values don't seem to be quoted where necessary. It should read `$val = 'aa', 11,22,'bb'`

Comment: That doesn't DO anything. you're just defining a variable that contains some (broken) SQL. PHP isn't a database engine. It doesn't magically recognize when you define an sql string. You still have to EXECUTE that query by sending it to mysql.

Comment: Using this type of query, you're opening up your database to SQL injection. It is better to use prepared statements.

Comment: use mysqli or PDO and bind the parameters. And people upvote this question as if it showed research effort. Geez Louise.

Comment: @Nyranith i tried it with only numbers too but no luck

Comment: @MarcB i definitely execute it but its not working at all

Comment: @Michael sorry i didn't got you

Comment: `table` is a reserved keywords. use different name for table name

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:

1- table is a reserved word. your table name can't be 'table'. (I assume you wrote it as a mock name).

2- the format of column names and values in INSERT query is wrong.

Try this before query:

```
$columns_name = "`$columns_name`";
$columns_name = str_replace(', ', '`, `',$columns_name);

$val = "'$val'";
$val = str_replace(', ', "', '",$val);
```